# How to find out the Python representation of Django fields?

Tags: django, django-models, types, field

For example I have this code:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    instance_name = models.UnknownField(max_length=255)
    instance_id = models.IntegerField()
```

I want to have the model name (`SomeModel`) and field name (for ex. `instance_name`) as an input, and the, and the output will be the python representation of that field (for ex.: srt, int, float...)

So it will be something like this:

```
def find_out_the_field_python_type(model: Model, field_name: str) -> type:
    # For example model = SomeModel, field_name = instance_id
    # return int
    return
```

I have tried this:

```
instance_id_field = SomeModel._meta.get_field('instance_id')
# Determine the Python representation of the field
python_representation = instance_id_field.get_internal_type()
print(python_representation)
# returns 'IntegerField'
```

But the problem that it returns not the python representation, but the type of Django field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think what you want is really do-able. The [Source code is available](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/_modules/django/db/models/fields/). It appears that the Python type is not a meta variable, but is hard-coded into the `to_python` method of the field.

The model is an interface between Python and a database. Not all databases directly support all Django field types. Where they don't, Django performs an encoding to store and a decoding to initialize a model instance.

This, for example, is the `to_python` method for a DecimalField from the above source:

```
def to_python(self, value):
    if value is None:
        return value
    if isinstance(value, float):
        return self.context.create_decimal_from_float(value)
    try:
        return decimal.Decimal(value)
    except (decimal.InvalidOperation, TypeError, ValueError):
        raise exceptions.ValidationError(
            self.error_messages['invalid'],
            code='invalid',
            params={'value': value},
        )
```

If you were determined you could run an iteration feeding plausible values into the `to_python` method until you get a successful return. Before doing this you'd want to check the field's `concrete` (True) and `is_relation` (False) for appropriate other handling.

```
instance_id_field = SomeModel._meta.get_field('instance_id')
if instance_id_field.is_relation:
    # ??
if not instance.id_field.is_concrete:
    # ??
for thing in (
    '0',         # should work for Charfield and numeric fields and Boolean
    datetime.datetime( 2023,1,1),  # for all date or datetime,
    0.0,                           # for above DecimalField,
    ...                            # work through the above-linked source for other probe values!
):
    try:
        x = instance_id_field.to_python( thing)
        return type(x)
    except Exception:
        pass

raise TypeError( 
    f'Unable to determine Python type of {instance_id_field}')
```

But this is really horribly hacky.